# access value in stacked dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a stacked df like this:

```
date        New Column                        
2019-12-30  Happy,A Series,Not Found                0.0
            Happy,A Series,New Number.             136.0
            Happy,A Series,Old Number               0.0

2019-12-31  Happy,A Series,Not Found                0.0
            Happy,A Series,New Number.             136.0
            Happy,A Series,Old Number               0.0
```

I converted this into a data frame.

```
stacked = pd.DataFrame(stacked)
```

Now want to iterate through each date and each line of the new column and access/print the string values of the new column, as well as the numbers. How can I do so?

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: Can you see the updated qs?

Comment: Please, post a copy-able example DF. E.g.: `pd.DataFrame({'New Column': [['Happy',...], 'Number': [0.0, 136.0, ...]}, index=[...])`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a data frame called `df`, you can access the column as dictionary element `df['New Column']`. Then simply iterate over the elements using a Python for-loop.

To split string (row) value into two-elements by set delimiter use `value.split("x")` where x is the delimiter (e.g `\t` for tabulator)

```py
for raw in df['New Column']:
    elements = raw.split('\t') # assuming the data are separated by single tabulator 
    print(element[0]) # Prints the "Happy,A Series,Not Found"
    print(element[1]) # Prints the "0.0"
```

**Note**: iterating over rows is not a very good idea performance wise. If you want to map the values to a new value, then using apply would be a bit better. Otherwise, I suggest you consider different approaches to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For iterate `MultiIndex Series` use:

```
stacked = df.set_index('date').stack(dropna=False)

for (i, j), k in stacked.items():
    print (i, j, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set date as index and iterate over:

```
df = stacked.set_index("date")
for date in df.index:
    column_value, number_value = df.loc[date, :]
    print(date, column_value, number_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction to @jezarel's answer:

```
for (i, j), k in stacked.items():
print(j, k)
```

This is all you need. stacked is a multi-index series and since you want to print each row, this is the easiest way to do it.

Although you may want to convert it into a dataframe where both "date" and "New column" are actually columns instead of indices. The easiest way to accomplish that is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(stacked).reset_index()
```